# Send Html text data to ActionLink in MVC application, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

This form searches for the value passed into "searchString" into a table and returns all the selected values.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="searchString" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

This form is supposed to provide an "ActionLink" which will be clicked after a search is made and I want the action link to pass the previously searched string "searchString", when the link is clicked but it is sending an empty string.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Author", "Index", "Home", new { searchString = Html.Name("searchString").ToString()}, null)
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I retain the value of original search string "searchString" in this "ActionLink"? Both forms go to the same method `Index()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MyFunc()
{
if (($('#searchString').val()).length > 0) {
 var url = "/Home/Index?SearchTerm=" + $('#searchString').val(); 
            window.location.href = url; 
}      
else
{
alert('please enter value for search');
}
           
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="searchString" id="searchString" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
          <a href onclick="MyFunc()">Search</a>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

@Html.Action("Controller","actionName", new { searchString = "searchString" })

the other way is this

var searchString="abc";
 @Html.Action("Controller","actionName", new { searchString = searchString })

Comment: the  other way is like this

Comment: it is giving me exception at run-time

Comment: Can you please let me know what had you write. Please share here

Comment: System.InsufficientExecutionStackException

Comment: please try this

@Html.ActionLink("Edit Record", "Edit", new {Id=3})

check this link

https://forums.asp.net/t/1963248.aspx?+Html+ActionLink+encodes+my+query+string+I+think+I+need+something+else+How+can+I+create+a+link+for+an+action+method+with+query+string+parameters+

Comment: I tried adding it to ViewBag and it worked but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it by like variable through your controller :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewBag.SearchString"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

your controller should be like this

```
 public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {

        ViewBag.SearchString = searchString; // This line send your string back to your view

        return View();
    }
```

for the link the same is applicable

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Author", "Index", "Home", new { searchString = ViewBag.SearchString}, null)
    </th>
</tr>
```